# What are the advantages of using a specific program for site maps and user flows?

Tags: users

I was wondering if there is a specific program where people make their user flows? Does it matter where or is it fine to use any?

Answer (score 2):

If there's anything I've learned about tools, it's to use what you're quick with.

For me it's Photoshop / Illustrator because I've been using it for over 10 years now. Been using InVision lately to show more detailed user interactions, but it's really just a nice cherry on top of lots of wireframes.

It really doesn't matter, just whatever you're comfortable with. If that means Powerpoint, use that.

**Edit 5 Years Later:** Yeah I soooorta stand by this statement, but after Adobe Xd, Sketch, & Figma making plugins, design systems, and prototyping BUILT IN to the software you're crazy to not at least try one. Adobe Xd has been my bread and butter since alpha, super easy to learn, can handle just about anything, highly recommend checking it out.

Comment: For a sitemap to be used, is it only when a website has a navigation that has sub navs when hovered? What if a website does not have sub navs? Can you still make a sitemap?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not limit yourself to specific tools. Generally speaking you should pick a tool that allows you to :

- **Work quickly**
- **Work Efficiently**
- **Produce results with the right level of details**
- **Allows you to share and print documents easily.**

For me Mindjet Mind-manager seemed to tick few of these boxes but was not an option at my workplace so I had to work with what I had- Axure.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I use Visio but there are free mind-mapping softwares out there that can be used as well. These softwares have major advantages over Photoshop and Illustrator in that they're far easier to manipulate decision trees and other nodes.

I've used Open Office and Dia and didn't like them as well especially when it came to PDFs. (The end points when the arrow joins the next node doesn't line up well.) LucidChart and Diagramly are pretty good as well and their PDFs come out better - but I think they're no longer free. I tried Bubbl.us and thought that was a pretty good as freeware. (Just went to their site - I think it's a subscription service now).

All in all Visio rocks when it comes to site maps and user flows but it is a little pricey.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use PowerPoint (or Google Slides) to build both, mostly because it's easy to use and as Zaxbit said, it's faster to use what you know. However, these are typically small enough sites that I can fit all of the pages on a standard slide. I would imagine dedicated software could better handle larger sites and help you to organize versus PowerPoint which is all manual. However, I haven't used any, so can't recommend a specific program.

If you build wireframes, you may want to use that same tool for consistency of output and easy editing. Programs like Omnigraffle and Axure have stencils and templates/widgets, respectively, for building personas, flows and site maps.

Answer (score 0):

I use [slickplan.com](http://slickplan.com/) for creating sitemap these days. It works quickly, has an easy interface, and provides various options to export so it's good. If I have a lot of time then I get it done via Keynote/Sketch/PS.